# SWT editable Combo - highlight text

Tags: java, swt

I have an SWT Combo that is editable. Users can select an item from the dropdown list or enter new text. My code also does some data validation and if the entered text is not valid, I'd like to force focus to the Combo as well as highlight the entered text.

My question is: is there a way to highlight all the entered text in the Combo? Unfortunately, there is no "selectText" method I think...

Thanks in advance.

I tried Baz's suggestion but for some unknown reasons the code while it works in a separate test project, the same code does not work in my program:

```
    comboViewerRes = new ComboViewer(this, SWT.DROP_DOWN);
    comboRes = comboViewerRes.getCombo();
    comboRes.setLayoutData(new GridData(SWT.FILL, SWT.CENTER, true, false,
            1, 1));

    comboRes.addListener(SWT.KeyUp, new Listener() {
        @Override
        public void handleEvent(Event e) {
            if (e.keyCode == SWT.SPACE) {
                Rectangle bounds = comboRes.getBounds();
                Point point = new Point(bounds.x, bounds.x + bounds.width);
                System.out.println(point);
                comboRes.setSelection(point);
            }
        }
    });
```

Comment: post the code you tried with. some one will correct it and answer

Answer (score 2):

Ok, there is no intuitive way to do this, however, `Combo` contains a method called `setSelection(Point)`. The javadoc of this method states:

> Sets the selection in the receiver's text field to the range specified by the argument whose x coordinate is the start of the selection and whose y coordinate is the end of the selection.

In order to select *everything*, you need to do is create a `Point`, set it's `x` value to the left edge of the `Combo` and the `y` coordinate to the right edge of the `Combo`.

Here is a code example:

```
public static void main(String[] args)
{
    final Display display = new Display();
    Shell shell = new Shell(display);
    shell.setLayout(new FillLayout());
    shell.setText("ExpandBar Example");

    final ComboViewer viewer = new ComboViewer(shell, SWT.DROP_DOWN);

    viewer.getCombo().addListener(SWT.KeyUp, new Listener()
    {
        @Override
        public void handleEvent(Event e)
        {
            if(e.keyCode == SWT.SPACE)
            {
                Rectangle bounds = viewer.getCombo().getBounds();
                Point point = new Point(bounds.x, bounds.x + bounds.width);
                viewer.getCombo().setSelection(point);
            }
        }
    });

    viewer.setContentProvider(ArrayContentProvider.getInstance());
    viewer.setLabelProvider(new LabelProvider()
    {
        @Override
        public String getText(Object element)
        {
            if (element instanceof String)
            {
                return element.toString();
            }
            return super.getText(element);
        }
    });

    String[] persons = new String[] { "this", "is", "a", "test" };

    viewer.setInput(persons);

    shell.pack();
    shell.open();

    while (!shell.isDisposed())
    {
        if (!display.readAndDispatch())
        {
            display.sleep();
        }
    }
    display.dispose();
}
```

You can type normally. Once you press <kbd>space</kbd>, the code will select everything entered so far.

Here are some screenshots:

[image]
[image]

Comment: The code works fine in itself. However, the same code does not work in my code, which is using a ComboViewer. I tried `Combo combo = comboViewer.getCombo();` and then added the listener as you suggested - nothing happened at runtime. The `combo.setSelection` line was actually run (I put a `System.out.println(bounds);` to confirm. I am not sure why it doesn't work in my program. Could this be a ComboViewer "feature"?

Comment: @user3229864 Well, you didn't specify in your question that you're using a `ComboViewer` rather than a `Combo`. I'll look into it.

Comment: @user3229864 Updated code. It now uses a `ComboViewer`. Same code still works just fine.

Comment: This is very strange. Your code works fine but when I copy the code into my program, it has no effect. the `bounds` and `point` appear to have been setup correctly but the `setSelection` method doesn't appear to have done anything at all.

Comment: @user3229864 can you check that the style bits of the combo are the same?

Comment: Do you mean the output of `combo.getStyle()`? The `viewer.getCombo().getStyle()` output is exactly the same on my machine using your code and my code, with an output of `570425348` (I used `System.out.println` to get the output...).

Answer (score 1):

Actually, what I found out is that the `combo.setSelection()` should take a point with the starting index of the text string as first argument, and second argument as the ending index, i.e. to select the first two characters in the text do, `combo.setSelection(new Point(0,2));` and to select all the text do `combo.setSelection(new Point(0, combo.getText().length()));`

Why it worked for Baz and not user3229864, could be the fact that Baz's combo is on coordinate 0, and user3229864's isn't.

Hope this helps!